# Possible to restrict direct URL navigation with Angular's ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, state, angular-ui-router

I would like to change states and navigate from my `/cart` to my `/checkout` states, but not allow my user to navigate directly to `/checkout` in their browser. Is this possible?

This is how they are currently set up:

**ui-router**

```
    .state('cart', {
        url: '/cart',
        templateUrl: './views/cart.html',
        controller: 'CartCtrl',
        title: "Shopping Cart",
        requiresLogin: false
    })
    .state('checkout', {
        url: '/checkout',
        templateUrl: './views/checkout.html',
        controller: 'UserCtrl',
        title: "Checkout",
        requiresLogin: false
    })
```

**controller:**

```
    $scope.goToCheckout = function(){
        $state.go('checkout');
    }
```

Comment: Do you need the URL to reflect the checkout state? If not, removing `url: '/checkout'` should work.

Comment: @AnidMonsur but then functionality like going back to the cart page is lost

Comment: True. If someone does try to go directly go `/checkout`, what is your desired behavior? Redirect?

Comment: @AnidMonsur yup, that would be ideal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When someone navigates directly to a page, they're navigating from an empty state to the state defined by the URL. You can use that fact to prevent navigation to `checkout`.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
  if (fromState.name === '' && toState.name === 'checkout') {
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go('cart');
  }
});
```

Comment: Would you just in the .run function when I initialize my app? That's where I've put this and it hasn't prevented the navigation.

Comment: Yes, in the run function. I fixed a typo I had in there. You need to access the state's names in the `if`.